# How to resolve 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' djangorestframework_simplejwt

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, pyjwt

I Depolying my django project to heroku but i am stuck, When i send request to JWT login it throws  'str' object has no attribute 'decode' , i have researched , came to know that PyJWT version is creating issue, my PyJWT version is 2.0.0, however people suggest to use 1.7.1 version of PyJWT, but i can't use 1.7.1 version because other dependencies rely on version of 2.0.0, how i can resolve this issue without downgrading the version, can it resolve by making some changes in site-packages?

I have tried changing the version of PyJWT, but other dependencies disturbed.

Comment: Could you share your JWT token and the package list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.